# How to remove keyboard enlargement in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, keyboard

I want to show keyboard smaller but causing problem. Please  compare both images, keyboard size is bigger in first image than second image and also vertical spacing between two character is more . I have already added Retina 4-inch launch image ,Retina HD 4.7 inch launch image and retina HD 5.5 launch image. Keyboard is showing proper in iphone 6 but my app design causing problem when i run in iphone 5. How I can show keyboard smaller without design problem? I have searched a lot but couldn't get solution of this problem.

This is image shows the proper keyboard size which I want in my app.

[image]

this is my iPhone 5 design image, here keyboard is looking starched.

[image]

see this is my iPhone 6 design image, it is looking fine.

[image]

Comment: Did you found same issue in real device?

Comment: yes, i found same issue in real device too.

Comment: please check this link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8001

Comment: hi, This link did not work for me, any other solutions?